# How to solve sonar issue Absolute Path Traversal in SonaQube?

Tags: sonarqube, traversal

In a web application the file path is stored in properties file.
The path is read from the file, and is passed as a parameter in the URL to call a servlet. while this path is used in creating a File object, sonar reports issue of Absolute Path Traversal.

Comment: The community [has discussed begging for urgency in questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and has firmly resolved it is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try encoding the path that is read from the properties file, before sending it as a parameter in servlet call. And Decode it before using it in the file object.
Like: String encodedURL= URLEncoder.encode(pathfromfile,"UTF-8")